# use Array of sub-document vs separate collection in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database-design, mongoose-schema

which one is better:

- use array of sub-document
- use seperate collection

let assume we have 2 collections A and B

collection A has an array of sub-document which each one has an _id
and collection B has an array of those _ids

or use a separate collection for sub-documents

example

senario 1:

```
A {
    name : String,
    fields: [{
      _id: id,
       name: String
    }]
}

B {
    name: String,
    A_fields: [A.fields._id, .... ]
}
```

senario 2 :

```
A {},
B, { fields: [C._id]}, 
C: {
    name: String,
    parent: A
}
```

this is just an example!

Comment: I suspect there are a couple of really good posts outlining the decision tree on this.   Neil Lunn (frequent responder) may have a good link...